# Puzzling average of correlated measurements

Tags: r, average, correlation, phylogeny

I submitted this question to stat.stackexchange

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147909/puzzling-average-of-correlated-measurements

but it looks like it fits more into that forum, as it may be more a computing issue than a statistic one:

I want to average correlated measurements. Given a set of measurements:

```
x = ( x1, x2, x3 )
```

whose internal correlations are given by the covariance matrix C.

A Chi2 minimization leads to the following average:

```
<x> = C^-1 * x / C^-1
```

But the following example puzzled me:

Let's consider the following tree:

tree.mod:

```
 (((oryLat2:0.3,(HLnotFur1:0.3001,HLxipMac2:0.3001)HLnotFur1-HLxipMac2:0.0001)oryLat2-HLnotFur1:0.05,(gasAcu1:0.01,tetNig2:0.02)gasAcu1-tetNig2:0.1)oryLat2-gasAcu1:0.4,danRer7:0.5)oryLat2-danRer7;
```

and do in R:

```
R
library(ape)
# Read the tree
tree <- read.tree( "tree.mod" )

# Extract a clade of 3 species
clade <- extract.clade( phy=tree, node="oryLat2-HLnotFur1")

# Measurements
x <- c(1,4,4)

# Covariance of the clade
V = vcv(clade)
      oryLat2 HLnotFur1 HLxipMac2
oryLat2       0.3    0.0000    0.0000
HLnotFur1     0.0    0.3002    0.0001
HLxipMac2     0.0    0.0001    0.3002

# Replace zero-entries
V[V==0] = 1e-5
      oryLat2 HLnotFur1 HLxipMac2
oryLat2     3e-01   0.00001   0.00001
HLnotFur1   1e-05   0.30020   0.00010
HLxipMac2   1e-05   0.00010   0.30020

# Formulas

# Weights
r <- 1/V
           oryLat2    HLnotFur1    HLxipMac2
oryLat2       3.3        100000   100000
HLnotFur1     100000     3.3      10000
HLxipMac2     100000     10000     3.3

#Mean
meanX = sum(x %*% r) / sum(r)
2.500008
```

I am puzzled because meanX = 2.5, which corresponds to the case of high correlation, while in that example the covariance matrix is almost diagonal, so I expect meanX = 3.

I must be missing something, any input would be welcome!
Thanks

Comment: Could you add some more context to your question? At the top you said you wanted to "average correlated measurements," which is pretty simple in the case of random variables (the expected value of the average is the average of the expected values, regardless of correlation). But then you started posting code involving evolution trees. Could you add some text to the question describing your application area and why the expected average value is not the average of the individual expected values in your case?

Comment: I have in that case 3 measurements, for instance I measure a bone length of 3 species. Given the evolution, these 3 species are not independent, there is a level of correlation between them, which can be inferred from the evolution tree. Now if I need the average bone length, I need to take these correlations into account. I hope that was clear enough.

Comment: I don't find this more clear. What do you mean by the "average bone length"? Is this the average over a sample of bones? If so, which variable in your posted code is that sample? Please edit the text of the question to make it clear what you're doing and what the variables mean.